# Check the format of user entered number java

Tags: java, validation, decimalformat

I want to check whether the user entered double value is in the format XXX.YYY. If it is then it would return true otherwise false. I want to know if its possible to do this with decimalFormat class. People have said to use regex, but that is out of scope for me right now.

Comment: so you want exaclty 3 digits before decimal and exactly 3 digits after decimal and you're taking input via Scanner ?

Comment: Yes and yes. It would also be from a file but of course for that I will parse it to double.

Comment: You can split the string by `.` and count the string length after splitting.

Comment: So i need to convert the double to a string first right?

Comment: If you are taking double as input, you cant really do anything. You will have to take `String` as input and validate if it is double and proceed.

Comment: @chimmy102 Just be careful if you are taking user input as a double, if they enter a value of `101.100` the two `00` will be removed because a double does not store that so when it is converted to a `String` it will appear as `101.1`.  You should take the input as a `String` and validate it.

Comment: @Nexevis is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @chimmy102 Not if you take input as `double`, you need to take it as a `String`, do validation, and convert it later.

Answer (score 1):

Pure java string solution:

```
  public static boolean isValid(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() != 7) {
      return false;
    }
    return Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(1)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(2))
      && str.charAt(3)=='.' && 
      Character.isDigit(str.charAt(4)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(5)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(6));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isValid("123.456"));
    System.out.println(isValid("12.456"));
    System.out.println(isValid("abc.456"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String s = new String("123.456"); // suppose it is string from your file
    String[] splitted  = s.split("\\."); //take the part before and after do in the array , splitted is array of two strings
    if(splitted.lenght == 2 && splitted[0].length() == 3 && splitted[1].length() == 3) // then it is in abc.xyz format
```

Comment: It might throw an exception in some cases. Maybe wrap everything in a `try ... catch`?

Comment: she said she wants that exact format abc.xyz when i asked in the comment

Comment: Your answer wont even compile. You should use `.length()` to get length of `String`. After that, try removing the `.` from `String s` to see if it executes fine.

Comment: did it, i misunderstood by array length

Comment: Did you see **[this](https://onlinegdb.com/ryoTU7bS8)** and **[this](https://onlinegdb.com/r1hfDXZHU)**? There are also other problems associated with this code. For eg: "abc.def" would just work fine.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat is it okhay now